# Bypass Linux password login with netcat or ssh or telnet

Tags: ssh, telnet, netcat

How can you bypass a password login with nc or ssh?  I type 'nc IP-address 13880' and it gives me the login form I need to bypass.  Can anyone give me any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were able to do this, so could a person trying to hack you. There's no way unless you know of a vulnerability the computer has. If you have physical access to the computer, you can reset the password and use telnet to login with the new password.